# Cannot implicitly convert IQueryable<string> to IQueryable<Proj.Models.Foo>

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql

My code:

```
public IQueryable<Foo> GetMajors()
{
        var query = (from u in db.Specializares
                     select u.NumeSpec).Distinct();

        return query;
}
```

Error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable.string' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable.Project.Models.Foo.'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Please include the definitions of `NumeSpec` and `Foo`: otherwise we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... yes: you're saying "take the `NumeSpec` of each item, now take the disctinct set of those specs; now return those specs as `Foo`s" - that just won't work.

I expect you mean "use the NumeSpec to find distinct-looking Foos"

There are custom implementations of `DistinctBy` that would do what I expect you want, but that only works for `IEnumerable<T>`, not `IQueryable<T>`. For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TValue> selector)
{
    var distinct = new HashSet<TValue>();
    foreach(var item in source)
        if(distinct.Add(selector(item)))
            yield return item;
}
```